# Flysystem: Optimize stream

Tags: php, stream, flysystem

I'm using the [Flysystem mount manager](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/advanced/mount-manager/) to create a sync strategie.

My code is based on the example on the website. But I've made a little change, I use

```
$manager->put(
    'local_process://my_big_file',
    $manager->readStream('distant://my_big_file') //Notice the stream
);
```

And tried to sync a files of `1Go`. It's working fine but take up to nearly `200` seconds to sync the file.

My question here is: Is it possible to optimize my server configuration (or code?) to reduce the amount of time needed to sync this file?

I've read [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/) and based on the Nagle's algorithm, I've tried to increase my `output_buffering` in my `php.ini` config. But `4096`, `8192`, `16384` or even `true` (my memory limit is `126M`) does not make any difference.

Should I try something else, or is it just the best that I can have with PHP?

Comment: To write streams you should use `$manager->putStream`. It could also be a result of the underlying adapter, which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using this between a `LocalAdapter` and a `SftpAdapter`. And yes since I use `putStream` the result is better